# The set of all sums of 3 primes covers almost all of $2\Bbb{Z}+1$ (result of Helfgott), what can one say about $\Bbb{P} - \Bbb{P} = 2\Bbb{Z}$ problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problem

Consider the set $\Bbb{P} = \pm$ the prime numbers and $\Bbb{P}_o$ is similarly $\pm$ the prime numbers other than $2$.

By Helfgott's result on the ternary Goldbach conjecture:

> Every odd integer greater than $5$ is expressible as the sum of exactly 3 prime numbers (2 included here).

We also have this almost immediate corollary:

$$
4\Bbb{P} = \Bbb{P} + \dots + \Bbb{P} = \{ p + q + r + s : p, q, r,s \in \Bbb{P}\} = \Bbb{Z}
$$

So if you quotient $\Bbb{Z}$ setwise by the equivalence relation:

$$
(p, q, r,s)\sim (p', q', r',s') \iff p + q + r + s = p' + q' + r' + s'
$$

You get the setwise isomorphism (bijection):

$$
\psi:\dfrac{\Bbb{P}^4}{\sim} \simeq \Bbb{Z}, \ \psi ([p,q,r,s]):= p + q +r+s
$$

Now use a "transfer of structure" isomorphism technique:

$$
x,y \in \Bbb{P}^4/\sim \implies x * y := [\psi^{-1}(\psi(x) + \psi(y))]
$$

to give the quotient of 4-tuples of $\pm$ prime numbers the structure of an anbelian group.

Then I wish to prove that $\Bbb{P}_o^2/\sim$ similarly defined but for $2$-tuples of *odd* primes is a subgroup, namely the one isomorphic with $2\Bbb{Z}$.

---

Clearly there is an embedding of sets:

$$
\iota:\Bbb{P}_o^2 \hookrightarrow \Bbb{P}^4
$$

Equivalence classe $[\cdot]$ on the left is defined similarly to be $[p,q] = [r,s] \iff p + q = r + s$.  This ensures that $\iota$-induced morphism is indeed a group homomorphism once we quotient.  Let:

$$
\iota([p,q]):= [p,q,r,-r]
$$
for some fixed and arbitrary $r \in \Bbb{P}$, and $p, q \in \Bbb{P}_o$.

Then the group law on $\star$ on $\Bbb{P}_o^2/\sim$  is...

Well, make sure you know first that $\sim$ is defined as $(p,q) \sim (r,s) \iff p + q = r + s$ hence "similarly".

Then you define:

$$
h := [\iota(x)], h:\Bbb{P}_o^2 \to \Bbb{P}^4/\sim \\ \ \\
\ [p,q],[r,s]\in \Bbb{P}_o^2/\sim \implies \\ 
\ [p,q]\star[r,s]:= \\ \ [ h^{-1}(h(p,q) + h(r,s)) ]
$$

This is indeed well defined because if $[p,q] = [p', q']$ then they sum the same so that they also sum the same in $\Bbb{P}^4$, so map to the same element $h(p,q) = h(p', q')$ and we're done.

It is a group homomorphism, by definition.  Namely we deployed the rarely seen used technique of "transfer of structure" between an algebraic structure and a set.

> **Question.** It seems too weird that I would have proven $\Bbb{P}_o - \Bbb{P}_o = \{p -q : p, q\in \Bbb{P}_o\} = 2\Bbb{Z}$ a well known open problem.   So please be kind enough to point out the flaw since I was kind enough to present the proof in full on 2 sheets of paper.

Comment: Why is $\psi'$ clearly surjective? You gave a few small examples but that's a long way from showing it in general

Comment: @FShrike Because $\psi$ maps onto all odd integers $\geq7$, certainly $\psi'$ maps onto all integers $\geq9$ by adding either $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Your notation is very unclear. You seem to switch between $\Bbb{P}$ and $\Bbb{P}'$, as well as $\sim$ and $\sim'$ without distinction. Please edit your question to be consistent throughout.

Comment: Also, what makes you believe that $\Bbb{P}^2/\sim$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb{P}^4/\sim$?

Comment: @Servaes will work on it now, but that's because the embedding is compatible with $[\cdot]$ respectively on each side of the embeding arrow (domain & codomain)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by an embedding being compatible with $[\cdot]$.

Comment: @Servaes Written this time much more comprehensively and cohesively :)

Comment: @Servaes What I mean is that the embedding is such that a well-defined isomorphism is formed.  I thought I needed some type of "compatibility" property at first, maybe I was mistaken.  Please see rewrite

Comment: @FShrike majorly fixed the post

Comment: As far as I know , it has been proven that every odd integer greater than $5$ (not just every large enough odd integer) is the sum of three primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a binary operation '$\star$' on $\Bbb{P}_o^2$ and claim that this defines a group operation. But it is not clear that this binary operation is even well-defined; in writing
$$[a,b]\star[c,d]:=[h^{-1}(h(a,b)+h(c,d))],$$
you seem to assume that $h^{-1}(p,q,r,s)$ exists for all $(p,q,r,s)\in\Bbb{P}^4/\sim$, or at least those tuples in the image of $\Bbb{P}_o^2$. Phrased differently, you assume that for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ there exists $p,q,r\in\Bbb{P}$ such that $n=p+q+r-r$, or at least for all even $n$. That is to say, you assume the Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: $h^{-1}(p,q,r,s)$ ?  I think maybe a typo

Comment: You could write out $h^{-1}([(p,q,r,s)])$ for $(p,q,r,s)\in\Bbb{P}^4$ but that seems a bit cluttered and I figured it would be clear from stating $(p,q,r,s)\in\Bbb{P}^4/\sim$. Feel free to edit.

Comment: $h^{-1}(p,q,r,s)$ exists by definition.  I did a transport of structure technique.   $h^{-1}([p,q,r,s]) = (p,q,r,s)$ or even $(t,u,v,w)$ should $\sum\{t,u,v,w\} = \sum\{p,q,r,s\}$ in which case taking $[h^{-1}([p,q,r,s])$ or the equivalence class under summing the components is appropriate and $[h^{-1}([p,q,r,s])] = [h^{-1}([t,u,v,w])]$ then by definition.  So I'm not sure where it's wrong.

Comment: You already give a definition of $h$. You explicitly state that
$$h(p,q):=[\iota([p,q])]:=[p,q,r,-r],$$
for some arbitrary $r\in\Bbb{P}$. That means that $h^{-1}([(a,b,c,d)])$ exists if and only if
$$(a,b,c,d)\ \sim\ (p,q,r,-r),$$
for some $p,q,r\in\Bbb{P}$.